# How to merge multiple text files into one csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to convert 200 text files into csv files. I am using below code I am able to run it but it does not produce csv files. Could anyone tell any easy and fast way to do? Many Thanks

```
dirpath = 'C:\Files\Code\Analysis\Input\qobs_RR1\\'
output = 'C:\Files\Code\Analysis\output\qobs_CSV.csv'
csvout = pd.DataFrame()
files = os.listdir(dirpath)

for filename in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=':', index_col=0, header=None)
    csvout = csvout.append(data)

csvout.to_csv(output)
```

Comment: why dont u use python's open method, open the file and write it with a new extension. You can also use pathlib's [with_suffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) method to change the extension from txt to csv. I dont know why u are changing it, but try out my suggestions as they offer more granularity and would even be faster since it is just a change of the suffix. also, as an aside, in ur program, it does not like the code after the for loop is indented.

Comment: Do you need a single csv file of 200 separate csv files? Your code doesn't match your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `os.listdir` gives you the list of filenames inside `dirpath`, not the full path to these files. You can get the full path by prepending the `dirpath` to filenames with `os.path.join` function.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dirpath = 'C:\Files\Code\Analysis\Input\qobs_RR1\\'
output = 'C:\Files\Code\Analysis\output\qobs_CSV.csv'
csvout_lst = []
files = [os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for fname in os.listdir(dirpath)]

for filename in sorted(files):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=':', index_col=0, header=None)
    csvout_lst.append(data)

pd.concat(csvout_lst).to_csv(output)
```

**Edit:** this can be done with a one-liner:

```
pd.concat(
    pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dirpath, fname), sep=':', index_col=0, header=None)
    for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dirpath))
).to_csv(output)
```

**Edit 2:** updated the answer, so the list of files is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I'd just add here that using `glob` is a killer way to navigate in your directories and retrieve files. Especially here looking only at csvs: `import glob; filenames = glob.glob(dirpath+"*.csv")`

Comment: @Arnaud, agree - I didn't include it because from my observations people on Windows platform tend to avoid it in their code.

Comment: Right, I was telling myself the same thing.

Comment: @ taras Thanks it does work but in csvout_lst it produce csv randomly I actually want list of Dataframes in the same sequence as in Input folder so to recognize the specific file e.g I have text files with names 105, 120 ,144 etc I want same sequence in  csvout_lst . is there any way?

Comment: @SumraMushtaq, sure - you just need to sort the list of files. See the updated answer

Comment: @taras thank you I tried  with sorted but it does not work. Is it possible to change the each Index row of csvout_lst with the original name of text file e.g index 0 = 105, index 1= 120 and so on ?